# Compare a list of records to a table in database and list their timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've a list of records (in excel) which I want to lookup in SQL table to find their entry date in table.
For example I've name of 200 customers in an excel sheet which are also in my SQL table but there are many others as well. I want to compare those users in table and find their date of joining the table i.e the date they were added to the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What columns do you have in the table?  What columns do you have in the excel data?  Do you have a column (or columns) which you can use to join the two sets of data together (such as a customer_id in both sets)?  Have you uploaded the excel data to the database? Is uploading the data the part you're struggling with?  Do you have a specific question with the technology or approach you are using?

Comment: Customer ID is a primary key in table, however in excel I just have customer names. Do you suggest to create another table from excel data and then use join ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any column such as "customer_id"? If not, create it in the tables as it will make it easier for you to select and join tables. You can use the alter table statement to add the new column. After adding the columns, join the tables and use the select statement to find the required record.

Comment: Yes there is customer id as  a primary key

Answer (score 0):

You must have a key to bind those data. Any other way can be dangerous linking these informations. Maybe, the way is adapt your application or excel to provide this bind between the data.

Comment: Yes there is customer id as  a primary key

Comment: If there is on both side(exel and application), you can use the customer id in exel to search the customers on database. is it right?

Comment: Yes but I do not want to search one by one, is there a way to use excel file in SQL query to compare all at once ?

Comment: You can use the list of Ids to go once in database.

`
SELECT * FROM Table a
Where a.id IN ([id_list])
`

ando so, compare the lists. You can too sort the lists(excel list and database returned lis) by id and use a comparable to do this once.